# ZINTERSTORE not working in https://try.redis.io/

Tags: redis, redis-cli

ZINTERSTORE command is not identified by Redis CLI on https://try.redis.io/.

The Redis command's guide highlight that ZINTERSTORE (https://redis.io/commands/zinterstore) command is available from 2.0.0 version. The Redis available on try.redis.io is with version 4.0.6 and it's still not working.

Can someone point out why I'm seeing this issue? Thanks.

```
> help ZINTERSTORE
(error) I'm sorry, I don't recognize that command. Please type HELP for one of these commands: DECR, DECRBY, DEL, EXISTS, EXPIRE, GET, GETSET, HDEL, HEXISTS, HGET, HGETALL, HINCRBY, HKEYS, HLEN, HMGET, HMSET, HSET, HVALS, INCR, INCRBY, KEYS, LINDEX, LLEN, LPOP, LPUSH, LRANGE, LREM, LSET, LTRIM, MGET, MSET, MSETNX, MULTI, PEXPIRE, RENAME, RENAMENX, RPOP, RPOPLPUSH, RPUSH, SADD, SCARD, SDIFF, SDIFFSTORE, SET, SETEX, SETNX, SINTER, SINTERSTORE, SISMEMBER, SMEMBERS, SMOVE, SORT, SPOP, SRANDMEMBER, SREM, SUNION, SUNIONSTORE, TTL, TYPE, ZADD, ZCARD, ZCOUNT, ZINCRBY, ZRANGE, ZRANGEBYSCORE, ZRANK, ZREM, ZREMRANGEBYSCORE, ZREVRANGE, ZSCORE
```

'INFO' displays the version as 4.0.6

```
> INFO
# Server
redis_version:4.0.6
redis_git_sha1:00000000
redis_git_dirty:0
redis_build_id:24cef40ebd18ad26
redis_mode:standalone
os:Linux 4.3.0 x86_64
arch_bits:64
multiplexing_api:epoll
gcc_version:6.3.0
process_id:672285
run_id:f8f55998b58ba17ed77d218a78cda00a51b7287c
tcp_port:6380
uptime_in_seconds:12882795
uptime_in_days:149
hz:10
lru_clock:6906059

# Clients
connected_clients:1
client_longest_output_list:0
client_biggest_input_buf:0
blocked_clients:0

# Memory
used_memory:34982504
used_memory_human:33.36M
used_memory_rss:42459136
used_memory_peak:35377616
used_memory_peak_human:33.74M
used_memory_lua:37888
mem_fragmentation_ratio:1.21
mem_allocator:jemalloc-4.0.3

# Persistence
loading:0
rdb_changes_since_last_save:4
rdb_bgsave_in_progress:0
rdb_last_save_time:1567186451
rdb_last_bgsave_status:ok
rdb_last_bgsave_time_sec:0
rdb_current_bgsave_time_sec:-1
aof_enabled:0
aof_rewrite_in_progress:0
aof_rewrite_scheduled:0
aof_last_rewrite_time_sec:-1
aof_current_rewrite_time_sec:-1
aof_last_bgrewrite_status:ok

# Stats
total_connections_received:944827
total_commands_processed:1841417
instantaneous_ops_per_sec:0
rejected_connections:0
sync_full:0
sync_partial_ok:0
sync_partial_err:0
expired_keys:13253
evicted_keys:0
keyspace_hits:335572
keyspace_misses:1003913
pubsub_channels:0
pubsub_patterns:0
latest_fork_usec:7905
migrate_cached_sockets:0

# Replication
role:master
connected_slaves:0
master_repl_offset:0
repl_backlog_active:0
repl_backlog_size:1048576
repl_backlog_first_byte_offset:0
repl_backlog_histlen:0

# CPU
used_cpu_sys:7408.67
used_cpu_user:3715.21
used_cpu_sys_children:1172.14
used_cpu_user_children:5570.36

# Cluster
cluster_enabled:0

# Keyspace
db0:keys=134447,expires=20,avg_ttl=125959035414186493
```

Comment: Does this work in your own local Redis install? The "try Redis" instance is very locked down and may have this disabled for some reason. If you need it, you'll need to take it up with the site owner, we can't fix it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow can't alter the configuration of the try.redis.io site.

Comment: I agree with what @tadman had commented - try.redis.io is just a way to experience some parts of Redis, for the full experience run the server itself (download/docker/whatever)